# why chunk files are split even though the file size is not 64MB?

Tags: hadoop, block, input-split

I was downloading twitter data using flume into hdfs. Though i have data more than 2 GB, my chunk file splits are less than 64MB. 
i.e. 1st file with 300KB,2nd File - 566 KB.
Why is that happening?

Answer (score 0):

That is because of your flume configuration.

read [this](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#hdfs-sink), you will have to set **hdfs.rollInterval** or **hdfs.rollSize**